# Spring security protect logout url

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, logout

I am using spring security in my project. I configure secured endpoints, using @PreAuthorize annotation. I want spring security to protect the logout URL, which I specified in the config file.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(LOGOUT_URL).authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl(LOGOUT_URL)
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler);
}
```

Here I permit any request, except logout. I guess that this configuration is only for @RestController endpoints. But how to configure it to forbid not authenticated users to use logout.

Comment: remove `.antMatchers(LOGOUT_URL).authenticated()` and add `.authenticated()` to `.logoutUrl(LOGOUT_URL)`

Comment: There is no such method. I found 'permitAll() and paste false to the argument. But it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In order to protect the logout endpoint which is handled by LogoutFilter, LogoutFilter should come after Authentication and Authorization Filters in security filter chain configuration.

We can disable default logout filter register and register our LogoutFilter after AuthorizationFilter as below:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   // Initial configurations
  // Add logout filter configuration
    http.logout().disable()
    .addFilterAfter(logoutFilter(), AuthorizationFilter.class);
}

@Bean
public LogoutFilter logoutFilter() {
        return new LogoutFilter(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler()
                , new SecurityContextLogoutHandler());          
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was trying similar things to protect `/logout` endpoint and perform additional operations in the logout custom handler. The problem was `Logout` filter comes before `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter`. Now I can add my own login inside logout custom handler.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to disable the spring security `/logout` default handlers and manage my own rest controller method. Actually, spring security uses `LogoutFilter` before any authentication filters check. So once we disable `logout`, like other protected endpoints, the request will reach up to your own controller and then you can add custom logout logic there.

```kotlin
http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/", "/signup",
                "/login", "/token", "/login/google", "/login/facebook", "/confirmEmail",
                "/sendResetPasswordEmail", "/resetPassword")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout {
                it.disable()
            }
```

My own logout controller method that works

```kotlin
    @GetMapping(
        "/logout",
        consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE],
        produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE]
    )
    fun logout(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        jwtAuthToken: JwtAuthenticationToken
    ) : ResponseEntity<Any> {
        val currentTime = LocalDateTime.now()
        logger.info("JWT Token Value = $jwtAuthToken.principal")

        // ADD YOUR OWN LOGOUT LOGIC HERE

        return return ResponseEntity.ok().body(
            LogoutResponseSuccess("Logged out successfully")
        )
    }
```